# Tell a float field how many digits to save after the point

Tags: mongoid

I'm using the mongoid gem and got some float fields the gets their value from complex calculations, at the end I get numbers like 23434.23423432423, I don't really care about more than 2 digits after the floating point, is there a way (instead of find all places in code and do a manual rounding) to define how precise my float is in the document field definition?

something like

```
field :result, type: Float, accuracy: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

use `after_update` hook and do rounding the Float field